# Image Component is not appearing on Android Emulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I recently started learning, react native and I added an image.

```
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      <Image
        blurRadius={5}
        source={{
          width: 200,
          height: 300,
          uri: "https://picsum.photos/200/300"
        }} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Here the `<Image ...` is not appearing on the android emulator but on the iOS stimulator I can see the image. I have reloaded the android app as well but didn't work.

[image]

If I debug from the android device I see these warnings below. Not sure if they are elevant.

[image]

Comment: @KetanRamteke That's an awesome catch :D I would have never thought of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your android emulator.

I can clearly see that WiFi is showing as disconnected, so probably your android emulator is not having an internet connection, and the reason you are getting that error.

Toggle the wifi of the emulator and after connecting to the net run the app.

Answer (score 2):

Use this way

```
<Image
   blurRadius={5}
   source={{ uri: "https://picsum.photos/200/300" }} 
   style={{width: 200, height: 300 }}
/>
```